# How to add comments from xsd to java classes generated by jaxb2-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb2

Colleagues, i have xsd schema where elements are commented. I generate java classes using  jaxb2-maven-plugin. Everything ok, but i would like to see comments from xsd (e.g. Client identifier.). Is it possible?

```
<xsi:element name="ClID" type="xsi:string">
                    <xsi:annotation>
                        <xsi:documentation>Client identifier.</xsi:documentation>
                    </xsi:annotation>
                </xsi:element>
```

**UPDATE**

In POM jaxb2-maven-plugin settings looks like:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/META-INF/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                    <includeSchema>**/*.xsd</includeSchema>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/java/com/comp/ddd</bindingDirectory>
                    <enableIntrospection>false</enableIntrospection>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: You may have to add a plugin to xjc, see for instance: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin

Comment: Laune, thank you. Could add some details according to pom below?

Comment: I think you can add documentation to complex types but not to simple types...

Comment: Try users@jaxb.java.net the JAXB user mailing list and/or repost your question here.